# Maven include test sources as dependency

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a multi-module project looks like this:

```
module-A
--POM.xml
  --sourceDirectory
    --SourceA.java
  --testSourceDirectory
    --testSourceA.java
module-B
--POM.xml
  --sourceDirectory
    --SourceB.java
  --testSourceDirectory
    --testSourceB.java
...many similar modules

ParentModule
--POM.xml
  --dependency
    --module-A
    --module-B
    ...
    --module-x
```

I have ParentModule in order to access the source files (SourceA.java) in A,B, etc. in Netbeans using "Go to type" without opening all the modules as projects. But it seems with the simple dependency I cannot access the testsourcedirectory sources (testSourceA.java).

Is there any tags that would allow my ParentModule to see and index all the testSourceDirectories in the modules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got something fundamentally wrong. Maven is a build tool ‐ see [Maven's Introduction](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html). It's not a tool for supporting the handling of your sources in the IDE of your choice.

Furthermore, a *dependency*, as declared in Maven, is a module/artifact/library your code relies on at *runtime.* So, there's no point declaring your test sources, which are used as part of the development cycle only, as (runtime) dependencies.

Comment: we are making this project for these 2 reasons: 1. in Netbeans we can use go to type to quickly access source files (big project hundreds of modules). 2. be able to hotswap code changes by compiling the module instead of the whole project. I know it is not the traditional usage, but just trying to see if it is doable.

Comment: Re 1.: It's a while ago that I used Netbeans. In Eclipse it's one key combination (`Ctrl+Shift+T`) to access any type by (even just partial) name. Re 2.: I agree, it's a good idea to separate a large project into smaller modules. However, I consider it a less good idea to introduce an additional, artificial (parent) module to try to achieve something Maven isn't intended for.